# What is 3kA in this mapping?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, neovim

I'm trying to understand how to make mappings in vim (particularly neovim).

Searching, I’ve managed to do some of the things that I want, but I can't learn what everything means.

Example: a latex snippet

```
autocmd FileType tex inoremap ,en \begin{enumerate}<Enter><Enter>\end{enumerate}<Enter><Enter><++><Esc>3kA\item<Space>
```

The `3kA`, what does it mean? What is it called?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! In this specific case, `3k` means go up 3 lines (see `:help k`) and `A` means append to the end of the line (see `:help A`). Vim's help is usually very useful, but you might need to know what you're looking for... You also need to track which mode you're in. In this case, there's an `<ESC>` preceding it, which is leaving Insert mode back into Normal mode.

Comment: Thanks! I will read with the help command! Don't know why i didn't thought of that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Vim :)

In `3kA` there are two "getting started with Vim" lessons in this, a path which @filbranden pointed you down, but to make this more explicit...
#1 is "motions" and #2 is changing from 'normal mode' to 'insert mode'.

1. **Motions**: `:help k` brings you to the "*3. Up-down motions*" section of the help manual, in which it states `k` = "up" and `j` = down, while explaining in more detail how these can be used (for example when you have `:set wrap` enabled and long lines are "wrapped" on the screen you can use `gj` and `gk` to move up/down through the wrapped line).  Motions can be prefaced with a "count", like `3k`.

   A) "*Section 2. Left-right motions*" of the help manual talks about `h` (left) and `l` (right).  The meaning of these keys relates to their position on the keyboard `h` `j` `k` `l` does "left" "down" "up" "right".

   B) Addition to left/right, up/down motions, there are *word motions* see `:help word-motions` for "*Section 4. Word motions*" that allow you to do `2e` to move right to the end of the second word, for example, and you can then expand on that `d2e` to *delete* to the end of the second word or `c2e` to delete until the end of the second word and then *switch to insert mode*.

   C) There are motions for text objects.  I've never even used these :/

   D) Gaining fluency in these motions is part of the *delight* of Vim.

2. **Changing to *Insert Mode*** can be done in a variety of ways.  `:help A` brings you to the `A` section of a chapter on that: "*8. Insert mode commands*".  Other options, as described in the help pages are `a` `i` `I` `o` `O`.  (I used Vim for several painful years only knowing about `i`!)

From the command line, *not* from inside Vim, you can type the `vimtutor` command for an introduction to these and other concepts.  Autocommands like `au Filetype tex...` which you typically put in your `.vimrc`, are a more advanced part of what makes Vim awesome :)

Now!...

This does not yet explain the "how to make mapping keys" part of your question.

For that you can see `:help map-commands` which brings you to an overwhelming list of options for the different possible *types* of mappings.  Mappings pertain to the mode that you're in, so you can having mappings for "normal mode" that are different from your mappings for "insert mode".

For example my `.vimrc` file has:

```
nmap <leader>sp :set spell<CR>
nmap <leader>nsp :set nospell<CR>
```

Which allow me to use toggle spellcheck on by  `sp` and off by  `nsp` (the `<leader>` is a useful thing vim provides for creating special mappings like this, similar to how "Ctrl" key works in many programs, and I've re-mapped leader to be the "space" key, see `:help leader`).

As you can see from `:help map-commands` (or `:help map` and you might also see people abbreviating `:help` to just `:h`) there are numerous options in addition to `nmap`.  Hopefully this helps!